# Why do the flames in my fireplace turn off and on constantly?

Tags: gas, fireplace

Does anybody know what would cause a gas fireplace to produce the behavior shown in the video? The flames keep turning off and on constantly.

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IMkAGilNMMbqO4eytSv9mfmveKKmoMur/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to  Home Improvement. It's better if you include the info you need in your  question. That said, it looks like you have gas flow problems. What's the gas source? A tank, or city pipes?

Comment: Hello, I would like some tips on how to troubleshoot this problem. The gas source is city pipes.